# Stub unlimited times in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

RSpec allows stubbing a potential request as follows -

```
expect(@project).to receive(:msg).at_least(n).times
```

What about situations where I don't know (and don't care) how many times `@project` receives `:msg`.

Is there an "unlimited" stub in RSpec that tells it to always stub it for that example no matter how many times its called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `allow` if you don't care how many times it gets stubbed.

```
allow(@project).to receive(:msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `allow(@project).to receive(:msg)` (as suggested by @Huy) or `@project.stub(:msg)` will stub the method.

Doing `expect(@project).to receive(:msg)` just allows you to make an assertion that the stub was called as many times as you expected.

If you don't make an assertion about it, or make your assertion general (e.g. `@project.should_receive(:msg).at_least(:once)`), then it doesn't matter if the method was called more than that.

You can find more info in the RSpec docs:

[Method Stubs](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs)

[Expectations](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this today. The short answer is "no", RSpec has no such unlimited stub.

From the [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts):

> When expecting a message, you can specify how many times you expect the message to be received. If you don't specify an expected receive count, it defaults to once.

If you know for sure that your test will call the method at least once, then you can use:

```
expect(@project).to receive(:msg).at_least(:once)
```

If you don't know for sure that the method will be called, you can invert that and use a large number:

```
expect(@project).to receive(:msg).at_most(1000).times
```